# How to retrieve data from multiple tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework, and working on Boys & Girls Hostel Application. I decided to develop it as a WCF Service.

I have two tables

1. Master

**Tbl_Room**

- `Rm_no int` (PK)
- `Rm_Name varchar`
- `RentPerBed money`
- `SharingLevel int`

  1. Child

**Tbl_Bed**

- `Sr_no` (PK)
- `Rm_no int` (FK)
- `Bed_no int`
- `Status int`

I wrote the following function to retrieve data for the available beds but I'm getting an error ...and I'm confused about how I can do this...

```
public IEnumerable<Tbl_Room> Available()
{
    var avilableRoomWithBed = (from r in db.Tbl_Room
                               join s in db.Tbl_Bed on r.Rm_No equals s.Rm_No
                               where s.Status == 0
                               select new Tbl_Room()
                               {
                                   Rm_No = r.Rm_No,
                                   Rm_Name = r.Rm_Name,
                                   Floar = r.Floar,
                                   RentPerBed = r.RentPerBed
                               }).ToList();

     return avilableRoomWithBed.ToList();
}
```

Here I want to retrieve `Bed_no` which have a status of 0 i.e available

I am confused about the return type of `IEnumerable` and what I have to return

Comment: It would be better if you tell us what kind of error this code gives to you...

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: You have already converted the `avilableRoomWithBed` into **List** then also at return time you again convert it into **ToList()**!!! Your method seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching your EF like SQL - if you've got your relationships set up in the class correctly (i.e. a navigation property called Beds on Tbl_Room) then you can do the following.

```
var avilableRoomWithBed = from r in db.Tbl_Room
                          where r.Beds.Any(b => b.Status == 0)
                          select r;
```